# How can I move -lm to the end using a makefile for c?

Tags: c, makefile

I have the following makefile

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lm
DEPS = fileMake.h
OBJ = fileMake.o fileFunction.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

fileMake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

It produces the follwing output:

`cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lm    secondDegreeFormula.c   -o secondDegreeFormula`

I would like to move the -lm to the end and remove the extra spaces, like:

`cc -Wall -Wextra -pedantic secondDegreeFormula.c -o secondDegreeFormula -lm`

how can I do this?

EDIT:

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LIBS=-lm
DEPS=fileMake.h
OBJ=fileMake.o fileFunction.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)

fileMake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS) $(LIBS)
```

EDIT 2:

```
CC=cc
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LIBS= -lm
DEPS=fileMake.h
OBJ=fileMake.o fileFunction.o 

fileMake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: 1) The whitespace does no harm, I would ignore it.  2) Please show your resulting command lines after "Edit 2", which you think is wrong.

Comment: done, Just edited it

Comment: We can't help because your error shows a file `secondDegreeFormula.c`, but nowhere in the makefile you've shown us is any such file.  So clearly, you are not showing us the actual makefile you're using (or at least not all of it).  The error is not in the part of the makefile you've shown us.

Comment: the file .c is the file I'm compiling. It just has the include of the math.h

Comment: I'ts not putting the -lm when I run make file

Comment: I repeat: there is no reference to `secondDegreeFormula` anywhere in the makefile you've show us.  The makefile you've shown us is correct and should work.  So the error is somewhere in the difference between the actual makefile you're using and what you've shown us.  When asking for help please use cut/paste of actual content, rather than paraphrasing and providing something different than what you tried.

Comment: What is the actual invocation of the `make` command that you are running?

Comment: make secondDegreeFormula

Comment: Well, there you go.  You're asking make to build a program named `secondDegreeFormula`, but you haven't told it how to build that program.  You told it how to build a program named `fileMake`.  So, certainly it won't work.

Comment: I think the problem is with the following lines, but I don't know how to solve it:

Comment: float x1=(-b-sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);
  float x2=(-b+sqrt(b*b-4*a*c))/(2*a);

Comment: The problem is in your makefile.  If you want to build a program named `secondDegreeFormula` from a source file named `secondDegreeFormula.c`, why are you using a makefile that builds a program named `fileMake` from source files named `fileMake.c` and `fileFunction.c`?  You should create a rule in your makefile that tells make how to build `secondDegreeFormula` from `secondDegreeFormula.c`, and adds the `$(LIBS)` variable to the link line.  Then you won't get the linker error about missing `sqrt`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the dynamic libraries a separate variable and include that where appropriate.

```
CFLAGS= -Wall -Wextra -pedantic
LIBS= -lm

...


fileMake: $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIBS)
```

Comment: I tried to edit it, as per my edit and it didn't work, what did I do wrong?

Comment: @DuarteArribas That's not what I wrote.  Try again as shown.

Comment: I tried to edit it again, but still didn't work. Also tried with adding the line `%.o: %.c $(DEPS)
    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)`, but still nothing.